# Problem with Validating the Integer Value in Java

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, validation

hi i am using **Eclipse Rcp** and i need to validate the textbox  that only accept the integer value for that i have use the code

```
 txtCapacity.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent EVT) {                     

                    if((EVT.character>='0' && EVT.character<='9')){
                          txtCapacity.setEditable(true);                    
                           txtCapacity.setEditable(true);

                      } else {
                          txtCapacity.setEditable(false);
                             System.out.println("enter only the numeric number");                                  
                      }
              }
      });
```

It validates But the Problem with this one is that i cannot **use the Backspace key** for deleteting the number. and please tell me idea for Validating the decimal too.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a listener, you can empty the text field, instead of making it not-editable. You can do something like this, the snippet is based upon your code.

```
txtCapacity.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent EVT) {                     
             if(!(EVT.character>='0' && EVT.character<='9')){
                    txtCapabity.setText(""); 
             }
        }
});
```

Or better if you use `JFormattedTextField`. I'm not sure if you have that in SWT, even if you don't then try to look for the similar.

Comment: well this code is allowing the character too. yea i am using the swt

Comment: Ansari thanks a lot for that i am going to vote up...can u have any idea for allowing decimal number

Comment: @Dinup: If you want to allow strict decimal than you need to some other event to handle that. Otherwise, if integer and decimal both would be fine for you, then make a check in the same method for multiple periods. I mean allow only one period, next time you find a period chop that off and reset the value back to the textfield.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use the `KeyListener`! Use a `VerifyListener` instead as this will handle paste, backspace, replace.....

E.g.

```
text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
  @Override
  public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
    final String oldS = text.getText();
    final String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

    try {
      new BigDecimal(newS);
      // value is decimal
    } catch (final NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
      // value is not decimal
      e.doit = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use the FormattedTextField-Widget from Nebular, see http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/formattedtext/formattedtext.php
The advantage is that you only have to provide a pattern, there is no need to write your own listeners..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to validate if the number:

```
    public static int validateInteger(String number)
    {
        int i = -1;

        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {}
        catch (NullPointerException npe)
        {}

        return i;
    }
```

If the function returns a value less than zero, then it is not a valid positive number.

Answer (score 0):

For validating if a `value` is infact decimal or not, you can simply use -

```
try {
        new BigDecimal(value.toString());
        // value is decimal
} catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
    // value is not decimal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set a [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) on your text box. You can implement a customer Document to filter for valid input to satisfy your requirements. Each time text is added or removed from your field, the Document will check if the overall input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {                     

        char c=evt.getKeyChar();
        if(Character.isLetter(c))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE ENTER A DIGIT", "INVALID NUMBER", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            txtfield.setBackground(Color.PINK);
            txtfield.setText("");

            String s = txtfield.getText();
            if(s.length() == 0){
                txtfield.setBackground(Color.PINK);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txtfield.setBackground(Color.white);
        }            
    }
});
```

Comment: if(s.length() == 0){
                    txtfield.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                }
is not working but m still working on it. Sorry about that

Comment: You can try this one chetan txtfield.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(warnColor));